# What are the viewpoint and lexical aspects of the following two "stand"?

Tags: tense, aspect

What are the viewpoint and lexical aspects of the following two **stand**?

> You **stand** to make a lot from this deal.
>
> They **stand** accused of crimes against humanity.

Would it be possible to use the present progressive tense here instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *stand*s in both sentences are *stative*:<sup>†</sup> they describe, respectively, the economic and legal *status* of the subjects. *States* are inherently *imperfective*.

As you know, stative verbs are not usually cast in the progressive construction, because they already have the imperfective sense which that construction bestows. When they are cast in the progressive, there is usually a sense that the state is at least potentially temporary; for instance, “You're standing in my way” is usually said to induce someone to get *out* of your way. “You’re standing to make a lot from this deal” is possible—you might use it, for instance, if you were trying to induce someone to moderate his terms, or to pass some his profit on to you! But *stand accused* is a fixed quasi-legal form; it would not be cast in the progressive, though *standing accused of ...* might appear as an attributive participle phrase.

---

<sup>†</sup> In fact, *stand*, *state*, *stative* and *status* are etymologically related. *State* is an Anglicization of Latin *status*, which is the past participle of the Latin verb *sto, stāre*, meaning “stand”: your *status* (or *state*) is, metaphorically, your ‘standing’—where or how you “stand”. *Stative* is a derived adjective. And Latin *stāre* is cognate with Germanic/English *stand*: both are derived from a Proto-Indo-European root *sta-*.

Comment: Can I rephrase them into "are very likely to"?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Not really. The first is closer to "You are in position to make a lot of money"; the second is a very formal way of saying "They are accused ...".